# Render views without any controller in Play

Tags: localization, backbone.js, playframework, client-side-templating

I am building an application using Play for Model and Controller, but using backbone.js, and client side templating. Now, I want the html templates to be served by Play without any backing controller. I know I could put my templates in the public directory, but I would like to use Play's templating engine for putting in the strings in my template from the message file. I do not need any other data, and hence dont want the pain of creating a dummy controller for each template. Can I do this with Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a single controller and pass in the template name as a parameter, but I am not sure if it is a good idea.

```
public static void controller(String templateName) {
    // add whatever logic is needed here
    renderTemplate("Controller/"+templateName+".html");    
}
```

Then point all your routes to that controller method. Forget about reverse routing, though.

I think I would still rather have a separate controller method for each template. Remember that you can use the `@Before` annotation (see [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#before)) to have the message string handling in exactly one place, that is executed before each controller method. By using the `@With` annotation you can even have this logic in a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template engine from any place in your code:

```
String result = TemplateLoader.load("Folder/template.html").render(data);
```